# Stack Overflow Subquery Tag Synonyms

Tags: support, retag-request, synonym-request

The Stack Overflow tag [subquery](/questions/tagged/subquery) currently has 1 synonym, [subqueries](/questions/tagged/subqueries).  There exist two tags, [subselect](/questions/tagged/subselect) and [sql-subselect](/questions/tagged/sql-subselect) that I'd like to recommend be reclassified as synonyms of [subquery](/questions/tagged/subquery).